# paypal sandbox notifcations - where do buyer notifications go?

Tags: testing, paypal, notifications, sandbox

I am using the paypal sandbox to test the full process for a buy now button.  Everything goes fine, except, I cannot find where confirmation emails go for the buyer.  I have logged into the sandbox under the buyer email.  I have logged into the developer email and checked the notifications sent to the developer for all test accounts, and notifications for the individual test accounts.  The test seller account gets a notification email that there was a sale, but the test buyer account gets absolutely nothing.

Also, this is testing the path where the buyer pays with a simulated credit card number, and is not logged into paypal. (the buyer gives their email associated with their paypal test account, but this is the path where the buyer indicates they want to pay with a credit card, not their paypal account.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sandbox environment does not sent any emails because you can use any dummy/invalid email to create a Sandbox account.
If you have created your sandbox accounts at `developer.paypal.com` you will see the notifications inside your sandbox account.
If you want to send customized email notifications for any type of payments(paypal and non-paypal account) , then [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) is the recommended way to go.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  I did use developer.paypal.com to create my test buyer.  I can see a 'fake' email to my test buyer in developer.paypal.com under dashboard=>notifications when I log in using my paypal developer account (you can see 'all' notifications from there), however, that is only for the transactions where my test buyer has logged in to pay from within paypal.  When my test buyer chooses to pay from just a credit card (not logging in to paypal), there is no notification.  There should be, correct?

Comment: This is intended, but you should see all the notifications in the seller's account. Buyer account you will not see any notification if the payment is not made via PayPal.

Comment: So it is working as paypal intended.  It would be nice to have those notifications show up, as well.  I have discovered that I can also send out a personalized notification using paypal IPN, and that can be tested using the IPN simulator.  This will happen regardless of how the user checks out (through their paypal account or 'outside' of paypal using a credit card)  I am doing this for a charity and so we like to send personalized thanks for every purchase/donation.  I like to test that regardless of how checkout is done.  Thanks.  I think this question is answered!

Comment: Yeah, IPN is recommended for sending customized email notifications for any type of payments(my bad, forgot to mention about IPN in first place) . Glad you figured it out.